# Stored procedure that deletes records by looping through Id's

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I am really confused on how to write this proc. Here is what needs to be done.

I have 3 tables laid out as follows:

tblObject {ObjectId, MasterId}

tblAnotherObject {ObjectId}

tblFurtherObject {ObjectId}

I need a proc that can delete the rows in 'tblAnotherObject' and 'tblFurtherObject' that contain an 'ObjectId' that does NOT have a matching 'ObjectId' in 'tblObject' that is paired with a passed in 'MasterId' to the proc.

I have been banging my head against a wall for hours today, and I have no clue how to write something like this...thank you so much ahead of time.

Comment: this part "that is paired with a passed in 'MasterId' to the proc" isnt clear. Could you elaborate a bit on this part?

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Comment: @InSane - Say tblObject contains a row that has MasterId = 4 and ObjectId = 15. I want to delete all rows in the other two tables that have ObjectId = 15. However, if tblObject has MasterId = 5 and ObjectId = 15, and I pass in @MasterId = 4, and there is no record that has MasterId = 4 and ObjectId = 15, those rows do not need to be deleted.

Comment: Your questions says those that do not match, but your comment says the objectid's that match--which of the two is correct?

Comment: @OMG - the rows that contain an 'ObjectId' that does NOT have a matching 'ObjectId'/'MasterId' pair in tblObject need to be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need a proc that can delete the rows in 'tblAnotherObject' and 'tblFurtherObject' that contain an 'ObjectId' that does NOT have a matching 'ObjectId' in 'tblObject' that is paired with a passed in 'MasterId' to the proc.

Use:

```
DELETE FROM TBLANOTHEROBJECT
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM TBLOBJECT o
                   WHERE o.masterid = @masterid
                     AND o.objectid = TBLANOTHEROBJECT.objectid)

DELETE FROM TBLFURTHEROBJECT
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM TBLOBJECT o
                   WHERE o.masterid = @masterid
                     AND o.objectid = TBLFURTHEROBJECT.objectid)
```

---

> Say tblObject contains a row that has MasterId = 4 and ObjectId = 15. I want to delete all rows in the other two tables that have ObjectId = 15.

That's the opposite - use:

```
DELETE FROM TBLANOTHEROBJECT
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                FROM TBLOBJECT o
               WHERE o.masterid = @masterid
                 AND o.objectid = TBLANOTHEROBJECT.objectid)

DELETE FROM TBLFURTHEROBJECT
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                FROM TBLOBJECT o
               WHERE o.masterid = @masterid
                 AND o.objectid = TBLFURTHEROBJECT.objectid)
```